# Как сделать дублирование элемента в vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, task

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при клике на определённую кнопку дублировался таск ( задание ) в `ToDo` листе на `vue` и, так-же, сохранялся в `localStorage`

Вот код `HTML`:

```
<ul v-for='(task, index) in filtered'>
  <li><span v-if="task !== editingTask" @click="editTask(task)">{{ task.name }}</span><input type="text" v-if="task === editingTask" v-auto-focus class="left" @keyup.enter="endEditing(task)" v-model="task.name"></li>
  <li><button class="btn btn-primary">Дублировать</button></li>
  <li><button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" v-on:click="deleteTask(task)">Удалить</button></li>
</ul>
```

Вот `Vue` код:

```
    var keyLocal = 'vue-js'
    var todoStorage = {
      fetch: function () {
        var todos = localStorage.getItem(keyLocal)
        return  typeof(todos !== "undefined") ? JSON.parse(todos) : []
      },
      save: function (todos) {
        localStorage.setItem(keyLocal, JSON.stringify(todos));
      }
    }
   var app = new Vue({
      el: '#taskApp',
      data: {
        search: '',
        inputVal: '',
        changeVal: '',
        editingTask: '',
        show: false,
        tasks: []
      },
    watch: {
      tasks: {
        handler: function(tasks) {
          todoStorage.save(tasks);
        }
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.tasks = todoStorage.fetch()
    },
      methods: {
      // Добавление таска
        addTask: function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if(this.inputVal){
            this.tasks.push({
              name: this.inputVal,
              status: false,
            })
          }
        },
      // Удаление таска
        deleteTask: function(task) {
          let index = this.tasks.indexOf(task)
          this.tasks.splice(index, 1)
        },
      // Редактирование таска
        editTask: function (task) {
          this.editingTask = task;
        },
      // Окончание редактирования и занесение 
        endEditing: function () {
          this.editingTask = null
          localStorage.setItem(keyLocal, JSON.stringify(this.tasks))
        }
    },
    computed: {
      filtered () {
        return this.tasks.filter(tasks => tasks.name.match(this.search))
      }
     }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавляете обработчик на кнопку, в нем реализуете дублирование таска:

```
dublicateTask(task) {
 this.tasks.push({...task})
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но проблему уже решил `dbl: function(task, index) {
          this.tasks.splice(index, 0, Object.assign({}, task))
        }`

Answer (score 1):

На обработчик кнопки добавляете новый элемент в `"filtered"`.

Comment: Если не трудно, не могли бы переформулировать?

Comment: @Кенан Возможно я не правильно понял вопрос , теоретически вы хотите дублировать ul по клику на кнопку "дублировать" ? Просто добавляйте новый элемент в ваш обьект\массив filtered .

Comment: Да, я хочу дублировать ul по клику на кнопку "дублировать". Добавлю в вопрос сам vue код, да бы было понятнее. Скорее всего, возможно, проблема в том, что забыл поставить данный код